# Error when striping HTML tags using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the following code to strip html tags from `data` string.

```
$($(data).text()).text();
```

which leads to the following error in console.

```
jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: API to manage person entities in the customer care system.Operation Detail - Create PersonCreates a new personURI: /customer/v1/PersonsHTTP  Method: POST
    at Function.fb.error (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at fb.tokenize (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at fb.select (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.fb [as find] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.find (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at new m.fn.init (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at m (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at eval (eval at render (pg-top-assets-table.js:17), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at render (pg-top-assets-table.js:17)
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:18
```

the string is as following,

```
API to manage person entities in the customer care system.<p style="text-decoration: underline;"><h4><strong>Operation Detail - Create Person</strong></h4></p><p>Creates a new person</p><p><strong>URI: </strong>/customer/v1/Persons</p><p>HTTP  Method: POST</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$($(data).text()).text();
```

this is wrong go catinate like this:

```
$("#"+$(data).text()).text();
```

Comment: $(this).text($(this).text());
try this one, but i think its wrong also because you are setting text to itself